# redirect to new site except 1 node

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to create a redirect to a new site, except one node and 2 folders.

The exception for folder1 and folder2 is working good, but not for "node-path"

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond $1 !^folder1
    RewriteCond $1 !^folder2
    RewriteCond $1 !^/node-path
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newsite.com [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line with `/node-path` to:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^node-path
```

In a htaccess, there is no `/` at the beginning of the RewriteRule test url.

You can test all in one with:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(?:node-path|folder1|folder2)
```

Comment: Did you clear your cache or try with other browser ? Give an example of use of /node-path (www.domain.com/node-path ?)

Comment: yes, i've cleared the cache. it's a drupal node, maybe that's the cause?

Comment: It's only for url change, not for file system